# Java private method hiding public accessors

Tags: java, reflection, properties, jax-ws, javabeans

I have a class like this:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.String;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlType
public class Foo {
    private List<Foo> compound;
    private String bar; 

    // private method used internally to know 
    // if this is a compound instance
    private boolean isCompound() {
       return compound != null && compound.size() != 0;
    }

    // public setter for compound instance var
    public void setCompound(List<Foo> compound) {
        this.compound = compound;
    }

    // public getter for compound instance var
    public List<Foo> getCompound() {
        return compound;
    }

    public void setBar(String bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }

    public String getBar() {
        return bar;
    }
}
```

In normal use, this class behaves as you would expect. The methods `getCompound` and `setCompound` get and set the compound list. However, I'm using this class as an object that's passed in a web service built using JAX-WS. When the JAX-WS compiler sees this class, it ignores the `setCompound` and `getCompound` accessors, and the only property that appears in the XSD is `bar`.

After banging my head against the wall for most of the day, I decided to try changing the name of the private method `isCompound` to `isACompound` and suddenly everything worked as you'd expect. JAX-WS created the correct schema for the `compound` property.

What seems to be happening is that JAX-WS is seeing the `isCompound` method (even though it's private) and treating it as a getter with no corresponding setter and therefore ignoring the real public accessors for `compound`.

Is there anything in the Java Bean specification that says you can't have a private `is<Something>` method where `<something>` is also the name of a non-boolean property, which also has its own accessors? Surely anything using reflection on the class should simply ignore private methods?

Comment: Try adding `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)` to `Foo`. Also add `@XmlTransient` to `isCompound` to be safe. Oh, also, [it's pretty straightforward to access private members in a class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11483647/how-to-access-private-methods-and-private-data-members-via-reflection).

Comment: Generally speaking it is a good idea to avoid creating custom methods called getX, setX or isX, if X is the name of a member field.  It is generally accepted that these name formats are for getters and setters (isX being generally accepted as a getter for a boolean field).  It appears your environment is confused by the naming convention and you solved the problem by changing the method name to something that is not confused with a getter.

Comment: Yes, I know you can access private methods using reflection, but JAX-WS should ignore them, even if they have a getter/setter name format.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you change:

```
 return compound != null && compound.size() != 0;
 //To:
 private boolean isCompound() {
 boolean check = false;
 if(compound !=null && compound.size()!=0){
    check  = true;
 }else{
    check  =false;
 }
    return check;
 }

//or
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE) on the class and @XmlElement and @XmlAttribute on the get/set methods.
```

Comment: The implementation of the method `isCompound` is irrelevant as far as this problem is concerned. Even if it were just `return true` it would make no difference.

Comment: what about adding XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE) on the class and XmlElement and XmlAttribute on the get/set methods.

Comment: I solved my problem by changing the name of the method name to `isACompound`. My question is not how to solve that problem, it's about why JAX-WS (or whatever it's using) isn't ignoring private methods, which it should be.