# How can I instantiate multiple objects into a list?

Tags: java, string, list

I need to instantiate a list with multiple String objects. I am not allowed to manually add objects 1 by 1.

I tried multiple ways, cannot get method to accept it.

```
scrambleOrRemove(["TAN", "ABRACADABRA", "WHOA", "APPLE", "EGGS"]);
```

Method:

```
public static void scrambleOrRemove(List<String> list)
{
  int length = list.size()-1;
  for(int i=0;i<length;i++)
  {
    String otherword = list.get(i);
    if(scrambleWord(otherword).equals(otherword))
    {
     list.remove(i);
    }

  }

  System.out.println(list);
}
```

Comment: What is `scrambleWord`? And you need an `i--` after calling `list.remove(i)`.

Comment: `asList()` or you can use the `addAll()` method too.  See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24922011/add-multiple-string-variables-to-arraylist/24922034#24922034

Answer (score 0):

Call it like this:

```
scrambleOrRemove(
  new ArrayList<String>(
     Arrays.asList(
       "TAN", "ABRACADABRA", "WHOA", "APPLE", "EGGS"
     )
  )
);
```

Now that you have your solution, read the manuals and explain why this works and why it was necessary for your case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use java.util.Arrays.asList() method. So for your example -

```
Arrays.asList({"TAN", "ABRACADABRA", "WHOA", "APPLE", "EGGS"});
```

Perhaps not relevant to your example as you are removing elements from your list later but you can also look into ImmutableList of Guava for doing this in general - https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList.html

```
ImmutableList.of("TAN", "ABRACADABRA", "WHOA", "APPLE", "EGGS");
```