# What is best practice to amend an external library in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, libraries

I'm using an external library to create a customized live streaming app.

Here is the library I'm using:

https://github.com/cine-io/cineio-broadcast-android/tree/master/cineio-broadcast-android-sdk

One of the (few) issues I have with this library is that it forces the phone to use the FRONT camera if there is one. I'd rather force to use the back camera (or have a choice, whatever).

As it is, the class that manages broadcasting in this library does have built-in public methods to choose the camera upon initialization, and its methods are private, so I can't extend it.

My solution has been to download the library locally, compile it as a local project in Gradle (I'm usnig Android Studio). Then I directly amend the library files in my project. It works.

However I'm worried this isn't a very good practice. One issue I can foresee is that the library will get upgraded - and since I'll have made changes locally it'll be very hard to take advantage of new versions of the library.

QUESTION: Is there a best practice when it comes to modifying external libraries? Is it what I am doing, or is there a better way?

Please feel free to provide feedback on the question so I can improve or clarify it as needed.

Comment: Since you're using github you might want to learn about [pull requests](https://help.github.com/articles/using-pull-requests/). This way you can send suggestions to maintainers

Comment: So - I do know about pull requests and they are super useful - but making suggestions isn't quite the same as actually getting the library to do what I want, is it? You're right that I should share my suggestions with the maintainers though - that should be a first response when I build something based on their work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would fork the library and push your commits to your fork. Like this you can later on merge changes in the original library to your fork as well.

Answer (score 2):

GitHub has a great collaboration model, that allows you to [fork any OSS project easily](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo/). You can modify it at will, optionally, push the changes back in a form of [pull requests](https://help.github.com/articles/using-pull-requests/).

Once you have your code ready to build, you can use a full free continuous integration/distribution toolchain, that is built from a cloud-based CI server of your choice ([Codeship](http://codeship.com/), [Drone.io](http://drone.io/), [Travis-CI](http://travis-ci.com/) to name a few), a free instance of [Artifactory](http://www.jfrog.com/artifactory/) for your SNAPSHOTs (intermediate build results) and [Bintray](https://bintray.com/) as a distribution platform ([built-in into Android Studio](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=8099840) for other people reuse).

[Here's a video demonstration](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UwUK5RHcxak&feature=youtu.be) of the full stack and [here's the documentation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=26083425) of the Artifactory/Bintray part.

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection (https://stackoverflow.com/a/11484158) but it isn't a good way.
I think in your case it will be better to compile module from source and not to update it.