# Referencing a private class in JUnit

Tags: java, reflection, junit, private-class

I have a scenario where I want to reference a **private** `class` - not test that class.

I am using Spring `JDBCTemplate` to query `db` and using a row mapper (which is **private** class of dao) for mapping the `resultset` to my `object`.

Test case is mocking like 
`when(dao.method(query, rowmapper, param)).thenReturn(something)`

**Possible solutions**: Make rowmapper default access and keep test case in the same package.

However my belief is that why to make code changes for the sake of **test cases**?

I was wondering if `Java reflection` can be of any use in this or not ?
 I couldn't find any thing on that so if someone has already been through such thing then please share.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11483647/how-to-access-private-methods-and-private-data-members-via-reflection

Answer (score 1):

You can use Java reflection in initial method to get the reference to private class.